# Why does my recursion work in Swift but not Python?

Tags: python, swift, recursion

I'm a Swift native speaker and struggling to understand why my algorithm doesn't work when translated to Python.

When run in Python it never resets the x or y value to zero. For instance an input of 4 should give (2, 0) but in the python version it returns (2, 1).

Here it is in Swift:

```swift
func position(from index: Int, gridSize: Int = 32) -> (x: Int, y: Int) {
        
        if index < 0 {
            return (-1, -1)
        }
        
        if gridSize < 1 {
            return (0, 0)
        }
        
        let localIndex = Int((Float(index) / Float(gridSize * gridSize)) * 4)
        let qx = localIndex % 2
        let qy = localIndex / 2
        
        let halfGrid = gridSize / 2
        var x = qx * halfGrid
        var y = qy * halfGrid
        
        let nextIndex = Int(index - localIndex * halfGrid * halfGrid)
        
        let (nextX, nextY) = position(from: nextIndex, gridSize: gridSize / 2)
        
        x += nextX
        y += nextY
        
        return (x, y)
    }
```

And here in Python:

```py
def posFromIndex(index, grid):

  if index < 0:
    return -1, -1

  if grid < 1:
    return 0, 0

  localIndex = int((index / float(grid * grid)) * 4)
  qx = localIndex % 2
  qy = localIndex / 2

  hg = grid / 2
  x = qx * hg
  y = qy * hg

  nextIndex = int(index - localIndex * hg * hg)

  nextX, nextY = posFromIndex(nextIndex, grid / 2)

  x += nextX
  y += nextY

  print(x, y)
  return int(x), int(y)
```

Comment: Run with what arguments? Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Integer division is `//` in python 3. Not sure if that's related tho

Comment: Note that you can use `qy, qx = divmod(localIndex, 2)`; this will correctly perform integer division (like `//`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that these kinds of integer divisions `gridSize / 2` in Swift return intergers, but in Python `grid / 2` returns a float, even though `grid` is an integer.

If you to use similar kind of integer division in Python, you need to use the `//` operator.

If you correct that mistake (and add the default value for the `grid` parameter, you will correctly get the output `(2, 0)` for the input of `4`:

```py
def posFromIndex(index, grid = 32):
    if index < 0:
        return -1, -1

    if grid < 1:
        return 0, 0

    localIndex = int(index / (grid * grid) * 4)
    qx = localIndex % 2
    qy = localIndex // 2

    hg = grid // 2
    x = qx * hg
    y = qy * hg

    nextIndex = index - localIndex * hg * hg

    nextX, nextY = posFromIndex(nextIndex, grid // 2)

    x += nextX
    y += nextY

    return x, y


print(posFromIndex(4))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> (2, 0)
> ```

Note that you can also simplify the function by removing bunch of unnecessary casting from it.